# formik for validation and post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, formik

```
const classes = useStyles();
  
const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    fullName: '',
    subject: '',
    massage: '',
}

  const onSubmit = (values) =>{
      console.log("values")
    axios
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/sendmail/contact` , values)
        .then((res) => console.log(res))
        .catch((errors) => console.log(errors));
}; 

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit,
   
})



<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>

              <Grid className={classes.GridContactHeading}>
                <Typography variant="h4">Contact us</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid className={classes.GridContactSubHeading}>
                <Typography variant="h5">Feel free to ask for details, don't save any questions!</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                  <Grid item sm={8} md={6} className={classes.GridText1}>
                    

                        <TextField
                            required
                            name='fullName'
                            label='Full Name'
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            value={formik.values.fullName}
                            className={classes.TextFieldContact}
                        /> 
                        
                        {formik.errors.fullName ? <div>{formik.errors.fullName}</div> : null}  
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item sm={8} md={6} className={classes.GridText2}>
                    <TextField
                        required
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        label="Email"
                        fullWidth
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        value={formik.values.email}
                        className={classes.TextFieldContact }
                    />
                    {formik.errors.fullName ? <div>{formik.errors.email}</div> : null}
                  </Grid>
                  </Grid>
              <Grid className={classes.GridText3}>
                <TextField
                        required
                        id="subject"
                        name="subject"
                        label="Subject"
                        fullWidth
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        value={formik.values.subject}
                        className={classes.TextFieldContact}
                    />
                    {formik.errors.fullName ? <div>{formik.errors.subject}</div> : null}
              </Grid>
              <Grid className={classes.GridText3}>
                <TextareaAutosize 
                    placeholder="Massage"
                    minRows={15}
                    className={classes.AutoSizeTextfield}
                    id="massage"
                    name="massage"
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.massage}
                />
                {formik.errors.massage ? <div>{formik.errors.massage}</div> : null}         
              </Grid>
              <Grid>
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginTop:"20px", marginBottom: "20px"}} >
                    Send Massage
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              </form>
```

i have created form and validate using formik and yup and now i have to send it to the backend as apost request and get an email but here onsubmit part doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that your `onSubmit` function is conflicting with Formik's `onSubmit` function. That, or your validationSchema needs to be directly declared in your `useFormik` object. I edited it just a bit with some format changes.

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({ 
  email: Yup.string('Enter your email').email('Enter a valid 
         email').required('Email is required'), 
  fullName: Yup.string('Enter your FullName').trim()
           .required('Full Name is required'), 
  subject: Yup.string('Enter your Subject').trim().required('subject is required'), 
  message: Yup.string('Enter your Message').trim().required('Message is required')
 })
```

Comment: Ok i will add it

Comment: const validationSchema = yup.object({
 email: yup
  .string('Enter your email')
  .email('Enter a valid email')
  .required('Email is required'),
 fullName: yup
  .string('Enter your FullName')
  .trim()
  .required('Full Name is required'),
    subject: yup
  .string('Enter your Subject')
  .trim()
  .required('subject is required'),
    massage: yup
  .string('Enter your Massage')
  .trim()
  .required('Massage is required'),
})

Comment: this is the validationSchema

Comment: You should add this to your original post so it's easy to read as code. I'll take a look at it when posted. 

As a gentle correction, you listed "massage" multiple times in your code, I think you are looking for "message".  Just a slight typo, but if you are building this out for public viewing/job interviews you will want to make this change.

Comment: Added your custom validation schema, thanks to whomever downvoted without a reason/explanation :/

Comment: Don't treat Stack Overflow like a forum. Don't ask for feedback or replies in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `validationSchema` logic. If this log line is not printed on submit event click, most probably the form is invalid. So check your validationSchema first. and why do you pass params to `yup.string()` method. https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#string